# What can I use for doing local MySQL testing?

Tags: c#, asp.net, mysql

I want to test MySQL with ASP .NET locally. However, I do not want to host a local server. How would I simulate a local MySQL server using files or something similar?

Comment: Why don't you want to use a real MySQL server? The footprint isn't that great, and you'll get more realistic results, after all.

Comment: Is there a specific reason why you don't want to install MySQL on the local machine?  That reason can shed a lot more light on the question...

Comment: Echoing others - there's no substitute for the real thing. Why "simulate" mysql when you can just use it? If you're worried about the resources of MySQL running on your machine all the time, just give yourself an on/off switch on the desktop. But even MS SQL Server hardly registers a blip when it's not being queried, I can't believe anyone would notice MySQL running on a machine built after 1998.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depends on what you want to test.  If you want to test MySQL functionality, then you're probably going to need a MySQL instance.  There are other light database instances, as @ctford pointed out, but you run the risk of hitting differences between each DBMS that will hurt testing by making the test environment different from the target environment.

If you just need to test the code that uses the database, without wanting to have an actual functional database behind it (more of a unit test than an integration test), then a [mocking framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37359/what-c-mocking-framework-to-use) may be what you're looking for.  You would set up your tests to use a mock database and essentially pretend to interact with a database, with expected results, in order to test your code against it.

Answer (score 3):

[SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org/) is a self-contained implementation of SQL that you could use instead of a fully-fledged database server.

However, I think you should reconsider trying a local MySQL server, as it's really no trouble to set up.

Comment: FYI SQLite still has some limitations compared to mysql (no LIKE %% & stuff like that).

Answer (score 0):

Another option would be to use a web host (assuming a web based application) that has mySQL already installed and working

Answer (score 0):

Go for [wampserver](http://www.wampserver.com/en/). It puts an apache+php+mysql(+other goodies) stack on your computer. It is light on resources and packed full of features.